# Preventing nosetests from closing in Windows

Tags: windows, nose, nosetests

I'm running Windows 7 and am trying to run nosetests.

It's been installed and I can run it successfully, except that when I do run it (by typing 'nosetests' in the cmd window), it'll open a new cmd window with the output - but this window closes before I can see what it says. How do I prevent the results from closing so I can see them?

I'm a real n00b, in case you hadn't noticed.

Comment: Maybe you can redirect the output to a text file.  I don't know Windows, unfortunately.